how to assign colors to variables using gg_vistime
i wanted to assign colors to the same variables in different groups using gg_vistime but i can't seem to figure it out
here is my code
library(RColorBrewer)
myColors <- brewer.pal(12, "Set3")
names(myColors) <- levels(tambah$abb)
colScale <- scale_color_manual(name = "indicator", values = myColors)

gg_vistime(test1, title = "Test 1", col.event = "abb", col.group = "brand", 
                col.start = "start_year", col.end = "end_year",
                optimize_y = TRUE, show_labels = TRUE) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size=15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, color = "black", angle = 0),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, color = "black", angle = 0)) + scale_color_manual(name = "issue", values = myColors)

my data frame in a form of dput()
structure(list(start_year = structure(c(1356998400, 1230768000, 
1199145600, 1230768000, 1325376000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), end_year = structure(c(1388534400, 1262304000, 
1230768000, 1262304000, 1356998400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), brand = c("DELL", "DELL", "BREE", "DELL", 
"IBG"), issue = c("Materials", "Site", "Materials", "Water", 
"Site"), abb = c("M", "S", "M", "W", "S")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

trial
here's the result, it shows different colors on "S"s, and "M"s, i don't know which step i should do to achieve my goal (all "S"s use the same color, same thing with "M"s).
A help would be appreciated :)

From a closer but not deeper look gg_vistime seems to map a column of literal color codes on the color aes and using scale_color_identity. To color according to your manual scale using a named vector you could change the mapping using aes(), i.e. map event on the color aes, where event is the name assigned under the hood by gg_vistime to the column containing the events.
library(RColorBrewer)
library(vistime)
library(ggplot2)

myColors <- brewer.pal(12, "Set3")
names(myColors) <- levels(factor(test1$abb))
colScale <- scale_color_manual(name = "indicator", values = myColors)

gg_vistime(test1,
  title = "Test 1", col.event = "abb", col.group = "brand",
  col.start = "start_year", col.end = "end_year",
  optimize_y = TRUE, show_labels = TRUE
) +
  aes(color = event) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, color = "black", angle = 0),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, color = "black", angle = 0)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "issue", values = myColors, guide = "none")


